# Производительный фреймворк на node js с архитектурой MVC?

Tags: node.js

Сейчас использую express + handlebars. На клиенте MVC фреймворк.

Почитал статью с фреймворками и там большой выбор.
https://habrahabr.ru/post/316244/

Ишу высокопроизводительный (такой же как express), для крупных приложений, гибкий, надежный основанный на классах.   С большим функционалом встроенным, перспективный и активно развивающийся.

- Желательно, чтобы был единый код на клиенте и сервере.
- Больше для разработки админок и SPA приложений со сложной логикой, чем с простой отдачей html кода по запросу.
- Желательно чтоб была хорошая документация на русском или книга.